# Cannot delete a document immediately after it is inserted?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I've created some tests for my ElasticSearch functionality and I've noticed some strange behavior.  If I have a test that:

1. Inserts a document and confirms there are no errors
2. Retrieves that same document, confirms there are no errors and confirms it has the expected values
3. Deletes the document, confirms there are no errors and confirms 1 document was deleted

Then the 3rd test will fail because 0 documents were deleted.  If I take one of the following steps:

- Debug the test and put a breakpoint after insert but before delete
- Add `time.Sleep(time.Second)` immediately before the delete step

then 1 document is deleted and the 3rd test will pass.  In the cases when the 3rd test has failed, I've gone into my ES instance and confirmed that the document exist.

This leads me to believe that after inserting a document there is some span of time where *something* has to happen before I can delete the document.

My questions is - what needs to happen after insert so that I can delete a document and is there a better way for me to handle this in my tests than sleeping for 1 second?

I am coding in Golang and I am using the [Olivere ES Client](https://github.com/olivere/elastic)

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with Go. Elastic doesn't guarantee consistency as soon as the insert call returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch operations can be inconsistent.

You can check the option [`refresh`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html#delete-refresh) or [`wait_for_active_shards`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html#delete-wait-for-active-shards) if it fit your test.

NB: it’s always difficult to add test to an inconsistent system.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the term `inconsistence`. Storing and retrieving a document are `real-time` operations. `search` is happening in `near-real-time`.

While you can always search for documents, they will only make it into your result set once the data structures for search exist (typically the inverted indices). Creating and maintaining this data structure for every single document that gets indexed would be costly and inefficient, that's why the data structure gets created at latest when the refresh interval has expired (default refresh interval is 1 second).

Also, when deleting a document, the document does not get immediately removed from disk. It first gets marked for deletion, ensuring that it will no longer show up in any results. But only after some Elasticsearch internal housekeeping (segment merges), the documents marked for deletion eventually get wiped.

That should give you an idea why for search we talk about a `near real-time` behaviour, or what you describe as "gap"

Especially for unit/integration test you would want to make sure that a document can get found after having it indexed. You can easily achieve this by converting your index/write-request into a blocking one by adding the parameter `refresh=wait_for`. With this, the indexing request only returns, AFTER the data structures needed for search have been created. Making sure that in your next request the document is available for whatever action you want to execute.